On the ideal generated by a subset of a Lie algebra.
It known that for a Lie algebra $g$, a linear subspace $h$ of $g$ is an ideal in the sense of Lie algebras (i.e. for any $x\in g$ and $y\in h$, $[x,y]\in h$) if and only if $[g,h]\subseteq h$.
Now, I ask if, given a subspace $A\subseteq g$ as vector space, the ideal generated by $A$ in $g$, let's call it $(A)$, is the subset of finite expressions of the form:
\begin{equation}
 (A)=\bigcup_{n<\omega}I_n
\end{equation}
where the $I_n$ are defined inductively as follows:

$I_0=A$

$I_{n+1}$ is the set of all possible linear combinations of finite terms of the form $kx$ and $k'[y,x']$, for $k,k'$ scalars, $x,x'\in I_n$ and $y\in g$.


I ask because I'd like to know whether, when $g$ is a free Lie algebra and $h$ is a free Lie algebra generated by a subset of the basis of $g$, then the quotient $g/(h)$ is either trivial or free too. I believe that this should follow by a general principle of Universal Algebra similar to the well-known case of free abelian groups, and the argument that I have in mind needs the fact above.
I precis that for "free Lie algebra" I mean here a Lie algebra with a subset $X$ satisfying the Universal Property of free objects in the category of Lie algebras.
Thank you in advance for any comment you may have.

Your equivalence in the beginning is false. Take the center $Z$ of any assoziative algebra $A$ ((e.g. n by n matrices) then $[Z,A]={0}$ which is not $Z$ in general (for example if $A$ is unitary this is clearly a contradiction).

You're right thank you, I should have written "$\subseteq$". I edited the question. Is it now correct the argument?

Yes a subspace $I$ is an ideal of a lie algebra $L$ iff $[L,I] \subseteq I$. But if your lie algebra is semi simple a non trivial subspace is an ideal iff $[L,I] = I$ so you might have confused this with the semi simple case.
